# Docusign API - signature time tab

Tags: docusignapi

I am interfacing documents to Docusign via the API. I would like for some documents to show the signature time as well as signature date. But for most documents I only want to show the signature date.  A signature time tab would be ideal but it isn't available. Anyone know a work-around or know if Docusign plans to provide this feature in the future?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what you've tried so far? Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a recipient tab that shows the actual time the signing has taken place, however you can parse this information from the certificate of completion (and auto-generated audit history that is automatically created for every envelope that is created.

You can learn more about the CoC here: 
https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-history-coc